Ideas for cooling a small office space with direct sunlight
As the title says, I'm looking for ways to cool a rather small room (approximately 4sqm) during summer. Its southern and western walls are windows, and during PM hours this room turns into a sauna even though I've installed curtains. This room is located next to my bedroom, which has an A/C and a ceiling fan, but both are pretty much useless when it comes to temperatures in the small room.
Here's a quick sketch of the floor plan, just in case my explanation wasn't clear. 
Thanks :)

Window films that block/reflect the suns rays, window awnings will reduce the heat from the sun.  Drapes allow the sun to heat the air between the window and drapes.  These are the cheapest ideas.

Also, perhaps a floor or box fan blowing air from the air conditioned bedroom into the "office" (assuming you're able to leave the door—if there is one—open).

Is the floor plan with North at the top (northern hemisphere assumed)? That would imply that the issue is mainly in the afternoon, and that (depending on a few factors) you may be able to get decent shading and keep natural light for much ot the day. Knowing the vertical situation and what's outside would help too, in terms of access to easily fit DIY solutions

Is the room on the ground floor?  Do you have easy access to its exterior?

If the windows open and you are willing to open them, slat blinds can make a big difference when it comes to solar heat gain.  The advantage is that they don't block airflow (or indirect light) the way curtains or roll blinds do. The key is to angle them perpendicular to the light rays.  If you can't or don't want to open the window, something of the similar design could be mounted outside.

@crip659 thoughtfully mentioned "Window films that block/reflect the suns [sic] rays".  Recently, I saw a presentation that included discussions of blocking specific wavelengths of light (not necessarily visible) to facilitate interior climate control.  If you want to maintain interior light, but want to adjust the interior climate, you may want to research this further.

The infrared band causes the heat, and is the one that should be blocked if using films.

@EndAntisemiticHate the most effective films here reflect pretty much all IR (and UV), and some visible so the view out is only slightly dimmed; they also provide a bit of a privacy function as hinted at by Martijn's comment under my answer

Total coincidence, this came out today.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhbDfi7Ee7k   Strongly worth a watch.

@crip659 It doesn't matter what band it starts in, it's still energy and it's almost all going to end up as heat inside your room anyway (except for the very small part that escapes back out through the window). Since something around 40% of the total energy starts in the visible spectrum, best to block most of it.

wow, I didn't know you could use sunlight to cool anything

Ideas for cooling a small office space hit by direct sunlight.

Too little for an answer but one detail is universally recommended: Make sure to cool the room down at night (usually by opening the windows and creating a through current, or in your case with the help of the adjacent A/C). Obviously, that only works in places that are cool at night. The recommendation usually includes closing the window during the day when the air is warmer outside than inside, but that may not be practical with 4 sqm.

@ron What are you referring to?

External shade is the most effective reasonably cheap way. Window films are also good, as are silvered black-out blinds - but then you need to turn the lights on and can't see out.
On the ground floor I use a large parasol on the patio, almost touching the wall above the downstairs windows. That's effective and low effort, but doesn't work upstairs without a balcony.
But as it adjoins an air-conditioned room, a fan in the doorway between the two rooms would give you some almost instant relief from the heat. Ideally it would be positioned to blow cool air from the bedroom directly at you, because you can't reasonably shift enough air to cool the whole room very much - but if you're cooler that doesn't much matter.
One other thing is to start cooling early.  If it's so hot you need to sleep with the air conditioning on, leave the office door open so it's cool in the morning.  Otherwise try to get some cool morning air in there before it gets too hot, closing the window and turning on the a/c when outside gets warmer than inside

"and can't see out." small addendum: You can always see from the dark side to the light side. During the day you cant look in, during the night you cant look out.

@Martijn "can't see out" is in relation to blackout blinds, which are opaque

The cheapest and easiest way to stop the sun hitting a window is to add a roller awning.
Note that they don't actually need to stick out all that far in summer, when the sun is high in the sky. There's much less chance of it being damaged on a windy day if you roll it out just far enough that the window is in shadow.

Fixed awnings were common in many parts of the US before air conditioning was available, and are still seen on older houses. They can be a bit more expensive to install but should last longer.

Technology Connections posted this video recommending awnings just a few minutes after I wrote this :-)

A good option. A fixed metal awning can achieve the same result and might be preferrable in some locations.

Seeing answer I thought of the video immediately, before seeing you noticed it too. I also today noticed that this is not forgotten at all, on my way to work I noticed an ofice building with strange tilted bars above the widows, clearly serving the same purpose without taking as much horizontal space.

@TomášZato - I think the modern tilted bar shades are designed to reduce the wind load - and possibly just to look 'modern'.


this room turns into a sauna even though I've installed curtains

All the sunlight energy that passes through the windows will heat anything it lands on: walls, floor... and curtains. These objects then heat the air in the room. Thus curtains simply act as a radiator. They do nothing against heating from direct sunlight.
To prevent your room from turning into a sauna you have to block the sunlight from entering through the window and keep it outside. Sunlight is about 50% infrared and 50% visible light.
So you can use a reflective film, that will reflect most of the infrared and a proportion of visible light too.
Pros: easy to install, works no matter what the sunlight direction is, see-through.
Cons: can't be turned off, so it will also keep your room cooler in the winter. You won't get free heating from the sun, you'll get less light, and you'll lose that warm cozy feeling of basking in front of the window in winter. So it's not an optimum solution.
The other solution is an awning like Robin suggested, or blinds/louvres, but they must be outside. Otherwise they'll turn into a radiator, just like the curtains.

Pros: adjustable, so you do not lose comfort in the winter. More effective than film in blocking sunlight.
Cons: you have to adjust them through the day. Obstructs view (but you can roll them up to hide them).
On a south facing window, this is ideal. I use an awning made of steel pipe with vine growing on it. In the summer, I get shade, and in the winter, the leaves fall off so I get sunlight.
On a west facing window, it is less than ideal because in the evening, sunlight comes in almost horizontal... then if you want to block it you have to close the blinds almost completely. An awning wouldn't work well on the western window, because a large part of the window won't be in the shadow unless the awning is much wider and reaches much lower than practical.
Other options
In France these are popular, we call them "roll curtains":

However, IMO they suck. That's because a window performs many different functions: look outside, let in light, ventilation, let in or block heat/cold, block intruders, etc. And with a rolling curtain, either it's down and you're in the dark with no view and no ventilation (but not thieves either), or you roll it up and it does nothing. But if you want to leave the window open at night in the summer to let in the cool breeze, then you have to roll it up, so there's no security. Plus they're ugly and when closed the space between the shutter and the window gets extremely hot when the sun hits it, so not very effective against heat either.
Louvred shutters look better and are much more effective. They provide ventilation when closed, provide some security, and you can open one or the other, or leave them ajar, to block direct sun depending on the direction it's coming from.


There was an article years ago in Scientific American, where somebody had successfully designed a set of passive louvres to control the Sun in an orchid room. It turns out that there's enough parameters- slat depth, thickness, spacing, angle- to be very selective about the times of day and year that the Sun can get in.

I'd be getting some sun blocking shades, either exterior or interior, to help reduce the overall direct heat in the room. Then install a through the wall fan to direct the air conditioning into the room as needed. They are inexpensive and easy to install. If the door is tight fitting, you might need to install two fans, a supply and a return.  See photo below from My Cooling Store.com, who I am not affiliated with in any way.


You could also consider the historic type of "plantation shutters" still used in places like New Orleans.  These are installed (as other posters have mentioned) outside, and typically hinge at the top, with slats to allow air circulation that are angled to keep the sun out in the summer and allow it in during the winter (when the sun is lower).  Another advantage is that they can be lowered to physically protect the window during periods of high winds.
Here's a photo from a contractor in New Orleans (LAS Home - lashome.com, with whom I have no affiliation):


How fragile are these?  They look vulnerable to being knocked sideways, or to hail.

Everyone here seems to assume that the heat is coming from the windows. While I suspect it's part of the issue, I doubt it's the main one.
Depending on the room/house setup, much of the heat may be in the attic and it's simply radiating down through the ceiling later in the day because the attic has so much stored heat. The other rooms may also be receiving the heat, but are adequately ventilated/cooled with a central A/C.
The simple "solution" if this is the problem is to add a box fan or a fan to circulate central a/c cooled air into the room from the bedroom.
The better/more permanent solution is to check/fix the insulation between the attic and the room. Also insulating the attic from the roof would be a better solution to keep the entire attic cool so there's not a load of heat getting stored in the day and released in the afternoon/evening.

Set a fan on the floor to blow toward the ceiling. This will disturb the "heat dome" in the smaller room and let cooler air in.
